# initialization error in junit using Eclipse

Tags: junit

Running this as Junit causes Initialization error:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
//import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Assume;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import Test.BaseTest;
import Utils.TestUtils;
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class LoginTest extends BaseTest
{
    String UserName;
    String Password;
    String VerifyText;

    public LoginTest(String UserName,String Password,String VerifyText)
    {
        this.UserName=UserName;
        this.Password=Password;
        this.VerifyText=VerifyText;
    }

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]>readData()
    {
        return Arrays.asList(TestUtils.readTestData("LoginTest"));
    }
    @BeforeClass
    public static void Init()
    {
        System.out.println("Before class called ....");
    }
    @AfterClass
    public static void CloseBrowser()
    {
        System.out.println("Afetr class called....");

    }
    @Before
    public void openSite() throws IOException
    {
        Initialize();
        dr=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver=new EventFiringWebDriver(dr);
        System.out.println("Before called....");
        driver.get("http://www.rediff.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    @Test
    public void LoginTest()throws IOException,InterruptedException
    {
        System.out.println("Test called");
        //skipping the test case
        if(TestUtils.IsSkipped("LoginTest"))
        {
            Assume.assumeTrue(false);
        }
        String result=TestUtils.Login(UserName,Password,VerifyText);
        if(result.contains("Failed"))
        {
            //Take screen shot
            String filename="LoginFailed_"+UserName;
            TestUtils.takeScreenshot(filename);
            //error
            Assert.assertTrue(result, false);

        }
        //logout
        TestUtils.Logout();
    }

}
```

Stack trace:

```
LoginTest (1)
testSuite1.LoginTest
initializationError(testSuite1.LoginTest)
java.lang.Exception: No public static parameters method on class testSuite1.LoginTest
    at org.junit.runners.Parameterized.getParametersMethod(Parameterized.java:309)
    at org.junit.runners.Parameterized.<init>(Parameterized.java:280)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:24)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
```

Answer (score 3):

Yours **imports are not correct** if you use JUnit:

```
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
```

Use these instead:

```
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;
```

The error message expresses that JUnit is looking for a method annotated with `org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters` but it can't find any because yours is annotated with `org.testng.annotations.Parameters`.

Answer (score 1):

The Solution is so simple.
I got initialization error because I had selected the wrong text in the eclipse Test Class File.
So To Run the Test Java Class file i have selected the `Test Method Name` or to Run all test cases in the java file i have selected the `Java File Name`.

and then right Click and run the JUNIT Test.

Comment: Running the entire test suite will produce more verbose error messages than running an individual test.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but it seams junit doesn't like test names starting with capitals:

```
@Test
public void LoginTest()throws IOException,InterruptedException{
 ...
}
```

try changing it to `loginTest()`

that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I add J-unit to my project, it worked for me. Right click on project -> Click on properties -> Select java build path -> Select libraries -> Select add libraries -> There you select and add Junit

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem here is that of your Eclipse Build Path. If it doesn't have JUnit library added, it throws this error. 
Add JUnit to your project.
Right Click on Project --> Click on Properties --> Select Java build path --> Select libraries --> Select add libraries --> Select JUnit